# How to connect to Windows Nano Server via SSH?

Tags: powershell, ssh, virtual-machines

I want to run Nano Server in a Virtualbox virtual machine in a Linux host, but it seems that Nano Server only accepts access via WinRM using PowerShell.

I would prefer to find a way to access via ssh as it's possible with other Windows to incorporate tasks with this machine in my automation in Linux environment.

How can I access Nano Server via ssh?

Is there a clever workaround?

Answer (score 3):

There is a powershell module called `Posh-SSH`. If you install the module you've a New-SSHSession cmdlet. See this [link](http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2016/04/using-ssh-with-powershell/). Based on this you can SSH to your Nano Server installation. To add SSH server capability to Nano Server you've to install [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) (the link points to the install instructions).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He is asking how to ssh into the machine, not out.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: I still don't understand, I created a nano on aws.  I am running on a mac and want to ssh.  Anyone got advice.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to setup and install OpenSSH on the nano server.  Unfortunately, you'll have to initially do it via the Powershell remoting shell.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/installing-and-configuring-openssh-on-windows-server-2019/ba-p/309540

Basically, the article outlines:

- how to install the OpenSSH package on the server,
- decide on user passwords or public key based authentication
- fire up the ssh daemon to listen always, and through restarts of the OS